# Blank white page after deploying Laravel Vite (Vue) website to hosting service, with ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error

Tags: vue.js, deployment, vite, laravel-vite

I'm new to Laravel Vite (Vue) and recently developed a website using localhost. Everything seemed to work fine during development. However, when I ran the command `npm run build` and deployed the website to a hosting service, I encountered a blank white page.

Upon inspecting the browser console, I noticed the following error:
GET http://[::1]:5173/@vite/client net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

also, the Vue dev tool for Chrome indicates that no Vue instance is detected. Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved by deleting public/hot file.